# jQuery html on table no source available

Tags: jquery, response

I don't know if i'm barking up the wrong tree or if im just being a knob...

I am doing an ajax call and on succeed, I replace  of my table, with the returned response using .html.  ( I have also tried using .replaceWith(response) but that doesnt work either )

This part is all working fine and my table items are coming back and populating the table... however, when I look at the browser source, there is nothing between  in my source.. I am assuming that's something to do with the way jQuery returns things...

The problem is however I am wanting to grab the "Id" attribute for selected a.delete, but I am not able to get any value.

Here is a breakdown of my code... 
I have simplified the fields to take up less room

My View:

```
<tr>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddSample", "SPR", FormMethod.Post))
        { 
            <th>
            </th>

            <th>@Html.TextBox("CustomerSampleId", null, new { style = "width: 80px" })
            </th>
            <th>@Html.TextBox("CustomerSampleId2", null, new { style = "width: 80px" })
            </th>
            <th>@Html.TextBox("CustomerSampleId3", null, new { style = "width: 80px" })
            </th>                 
        }
        <th>
            <button class="button saveSampleButton" id="saveSampleButton">
                Add Sample</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

My Partial:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
```

{
    var number = i + 1;

```
<tr>
    <td>@number
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="@Model.ElementAt(i).Id" class="delete">
            <img src="/images/delete.png" /></a>

        @Model.ElementAt(i).CustomerSampleId
    </td>
    <td>@Model.ElementAt(i).CustomerSampleId2
    </td>
    <td>@Model.ElementAt(i).CustomerSampleId3
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

jQuery that does the save

```
$("#saveSampleButton").click(function () {

        //validate fields

        if (fieldsValid) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/SPR/AddSample",
                type: "POST",
                data: { data: data
                },
                success: function (pId) {
                    GetSamples(pId);

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong : Were all the necessary fields filled in?");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

  function GetSamples(pId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SPR/GetSamples",
            type: "POST",
            data: { Id: pId },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#Samples tbody").html(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

and when I have added some samples, and look at my broswer source, this is what I get:

```
<tr>
  <form action="/SPR/AddSample" method="post">                <th>
            </th>
            <th><input id="CustomerSampleId" name="CustomerSampleId" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="" />
            </th>
            <th><input id="CustomerSampleId2" name="CustomerSampleId2" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="" />
            </th>
            <th><input id="CustomerSampleId3" name="CustomerSampleId3" style="width: 80px" type="text" value="" />
            </th>                

               </form>            <th>
              <button class="button saveSampleButton" id="saveSampleButton">Add Sample</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Is anyone able to shed some light on whats happening and why I cant access the Id of the a.delete link???

Comment: If you're using Chrome, Safari or Firefox you can right-click the element and choose "inspect element". This should show the changes made by Javascript.

Comment: how are you trying to access a.delete? Plus don't view source to bughunt ajax material. The source shouldn't update with the dom. To see the changes, check them in firebug or chrome developer tools.

Comment: $("a.delete").click(function () {
            var projectId = $(this).attr('Id'); });